# Is it safe to use PG_GETARG_POINTER in a C aggregate function?

Tags: c, postgresql

I'm writing a C aggregate function for PostgreSQL, currently I am using `PG_GETARG_POINTER` for as follows:

```c
Datum my_transfunc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
       mystype *trans_data = (mystype *) PG_GETARG_POINTER(0);
       // Do some operations on trans_data pointer.
       // That make trans_data's memory content change. Then
       PG_RETURN_POINTER(trans_data);
}
```

Are there any issues (memory, ...) which my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`backend/executor/nodeAgg.c` says:

```
We compute aggregate input expressions and run the transition functions
in a temporary econtext (aggstate->tmpcontext).  This is reset at least
once per input tuple, so when the transvalue datatype is
pass-by-reference, we have to be careful to copy it into a longer-lived
memory context, and free the prior value to avoid memory leakage.  We
store transvalues in another set of econtexts, aggstate->aggcontexts
(one per grouping set, see below), which are also used for the hashtable
structures in AGG_HASHED mode.  These econtexts are rescanned, not just
reset, at group boundaries so that aggregate transition functions can
register shutdown callbacks via AggRegisterCallback.
```

Since the transition value is copied around, it has to be a `Datum` (e.g. a `bytea`) so that `copyDatum` can copy it correctly.

Since you are using a pointer (that's probably declared as `internal` in SQL), that should be fine; `internal` is pass-by-value.

You have to make sure that your `mystype` is allocated in a memory context that survives for the whole statement but is cleared afterwards.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help!

So as I understand, currently as I use my own transition type (mystype) , I should not use PG_GETARGS_POINTER that way but prepare memory by myself for transition. Is it right?

Comment: Even if you allocate the memory yourself, the value will still be copied. If `copyDatum` gags on it, it will fail. The value has to be copied around because different memory contexts are used; read the source for more.

Comment: @Laurenz: Sounds like the copy is specific to pass-by-reference types. If your aggregate is declared with `STYPE=internal`, I think you're fine. [`string_agg()`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_10_1/src/backend/utils/adt/varlena.c#L4699), for example, seems to be passing pointers around in exactly this fashion (though it switches contexts before allocating anything, of course).

Comment: That is right. You don't have to worry about types that are passed by value.

Comment: @Laurenz: I'm not sure I follow. Isn't `internal` pass-by-value? And `string_agg()` doesn't build `bytea` values, it just passes around `StringInfo` pointers; how is the code in the question any different? (Aside from the fact that we don't know where/when/how he's allocating the thing...)

Comment: Hmm, yes, you are right. A pointer would be `internal` in SQL and that's fine.

Comment: I have extended the answer.

Comment: Thanks you both for answering my question. @ Nick Barnes, you mentioned about string_agg() switches contexts before allocating things, can you please give me some clues on this?

In my case, the internal structure (mystype) contains one bytea* and one pointer to c++ structure which is wrapper as an object. And I already tried to allocate mystype by palloc, then mystype->cplusplus = newCplusplusObj, but it brings undefined behaviors. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I found it. Thank for you supports.